# How to convert XML to nested Dictionary using Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-xml

I'd like to convert a XML file to a Dictionary. The XML file is strucured as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Definitions>   
    <Organization ID="416">
        <Department Name="Facility">
            <Destination Employees="Something" Obj="someObject" Building="none" Type="Int16"\>
        </Department>
    </Organization>
    <Organization ID="502">
        <Department Name="IT">
            <Destination Employees="Something" Obj="someObject" Building="none" Type="Int16"\>
        </Department>
        <Department Name="Specialty">
            <Destination Employees="Something" Obj="someObject" Building="none" Type="Int16"\>
            <Destination Employees="SomethingElse" Obj="someObject" Building="none" Type="Int16"\>
        </Department>
    </Organization> 
</Definitions>
```

I'd like to use a nested dictionary, which can be conceptualized as a table such that "Department" is the row number, "Organization" is the column number, and "Employees", "Obj", "Building", and "Type" are the values to be found there. Therefore, I create the following class:

```
// Stores constant data of each tuple <Organization,Department>
public class DatSet
{
    public string Employees { get; set; }
    public string Obj { get; set; }
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and the following Dictionary to store the data:

```
// Nested Diectionary to allow fast access to XML content
public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<DatSet>>>;
```

The entire tree is represented as a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, DatSet>>` whose keys are Organization IDs, and values are, in turn, Dictionaries whose keys are Department names and values are DatSets.

With the following LINQ expression I want to convert the XML data to the nested dictionary. However, I am getting an error saying that *lambda-expression* cannot be converted to type *System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer* (in `org => org.DatSet.ToDictionary(dep => dep.Name));`).

```
// Converts XML File to nested Dictionary
private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<DatSet>>> XmlToDict(XDocument element)
{
    return element.Descendants("Organization")
            .Select(org => new
            {
                ID = org.Attribute("ID").Value,
                dep = org.Descendants("Department")
                .Select(dep => new
                {
                    Name = dep.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    DatSet = dep.Descendants("Destination")
                    .Select(dest => new DatSet
                    {
                        Employees = dest.Attribute("Employees").Value,
                        Obj = dest.Attribute("Obj").Value,
                        Building = dest.Attribute("Building").Value,
                        Type = dest.Attribute("Type").Value,
                    })
                })
            })
            .ToDictionary(
                org => int.Parse(org.ID),
                org => org.DatSet.ToDictionary(dep => dep.Name));
}
```

**EDIT:**

When I change the last line as suggested by ChrFin, the error disappears. However, no I am getting the following XMLException:

```
XmlException: Unexpected token. Name is required here. file:///C:/Data/projekt_2/Assets/Resources/DataDef.xml Line 6, position 72.
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadAttributes (Boolean isXmlDecl)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadStartTag ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read ()
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read ()
Mono.Xml.XmlFilterReader.Read ()
Mono.Xml.XmlFilterReader.Read ()
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ReadContent (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.String uri, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.String uri)
Input.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Input/Input.cs:41)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<DatSet>>>` as there can be more then one `DataSet` per Department?

Comment: Yes. You're right! I changed it. However, I'm still getting the same error in the last line.

Comment: I can see that the last line in `XmlToDict` is obviously wrong, but I don't know how to make it right. I also tried `dep => dep.DatSet.ToDictionary(dep => dep.Name, dest));` but I am getting an error saying that "lambda-Expression" cannot be converted to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following:

```
org => org.dep.ToDictionary(dep => dep.Name, dep => dep.DatSet)
```

This creates the correct result - see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oQbXOP).

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I am getting an XMLException now (see EDIT)

Comment: Did you use the exact XML posted in the question? Because that is malformated - I fixed it by replacing the `\>` with `/>` (see my fiddle - it is working there).